# Stay on the MPMoviePlayerController after playback finishes

Tags: cocoa-touch, media-player

I am using a tableview and when the user selects a row, I am playing the video associated with the row using an MPMoviePlayerController object. Now as soon as the playback finishes, MPMoviePlayerController is released and control goes back to the previous controller.

How can I prevent this from happening? I want to take the user back to the previous controller only after he presses the "Done" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar to this I think. What I wanted to do was have the movie stop on its final frame and put some semi-transparent buttons over the top of the still image. The way I did this was to store the final frame as a separate image which I loaded into a view beneath the movie player. You set `movie.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]` to make the movie fade to alpha thus revealing the identical image beneath it and not appearing to fade at all!

The neat thing is the buttons that I added **do** appear to fade because they are gradually revealed by the movie player alpha fade.